# Как сделать ответы на сообщения пользователя?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть массив с вопросом и ответами, например такой:

```
[
    'vopos' => 'что делать?',
    'otveti' => [
        'ничего'
        'что хочешь'
        ....
    ]
],
.....
```

И я бы хотел чтобы после отправки сообщения от пользователя, скрипт сверял, есть ли в тексте совпадение в одном из **vopos** и если есть, выдавался бы случайный ответ из **otveti**

```
function sendMess(text) {
    //text - это текст который отправляет пользователь
    
    //здесь мне нужно просто получить текст из **otveti** который совпал(хотя бы по части строки) c **vopros**
}
```

буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Вот пользователь задал вопрос: "Чем заняться?" или "Как быть?" и как здесь получить канонический вопрос "Что делать?". Тут никакими регулярками или еще чем не обойтись. Либо самому составлять список схожих вопросов и добавлять в массив, который будут приводить к каноническому. Либо идти в Python и строить сложную систему обучения компьютера русскому языку)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, что-то примерное такое...

```js
let input = document.querySelector('#input');
let button = document.querySelector('#button');

//---------

let arr = [{
    vopos: 'куда ехать?',
    otveti: ['налево', 'направо', 'прямо'],
  },
  {
    vopos: 'что делать?',
    otveti: ['ничего', 'что хочешь'],
  },
];

//---------

function sendMess(textQuestions, arr) {
  textQuestions = textQuestions.toLowerCase();

  let obj = arr.find((el) => textQuestions === el.vopos);
  let res = obj?.otveti[randomInteger(0, obj.otveti.length - 1)];

  return Boolean(res) ? res : 'В базе ничего не найдено...';
}

//---------

function randomInteger(min, max) {
  let rand = min + Math.random() * (max + 1 - min);
  return Math.floor(rand);
}

//---------

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let value = input.value;

  console.log(sendMess(value, arr));
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" value="" placeholder="Ваш вопрос...">
<button id="button" type="button">Подсказать!</button>
```

Comment: а как сделать по части текста чтобы отвечало? типа "куда" или "делать" и чтобы находило соответствие с более соответсвующим вопросом

Comment: @iKey Если вы хотите интеллектуального чат-бота сделать, а точнее, чтобы его кто-то за вас сделал, то, если честно, я сильно сомневаюсь, что кто-то согласится реализовать такое на бесплатной основе. Функцию `sendMess`, которая будет проверять отправленный юзером текст на совпадение с текстом в базе и выдавать случайный результат из определенного списка ответов, я вам реализовал, как вы и хотели.